# copy python script to new location wont update path

Tags: python, path, os.path, working-directory

Hi I am having a really weird issue with a simple python script.

I created it in one folder, A, and have later copied it to a new folder B.
However when I add folder B as a project folder in Atom and run the script, it behaves as if it is still located in folder A.

I can find no references to folder A, nothing in the script for sure and can't see anything in file properties that should give this result??

Running os.path.realpath() gives me the old folder A, and any output files I generate while running the script in folder B gets saved to folder A.

Am I missing a "magic" way of copying python scripts to new locations?

Hope someone can help :)

-Thomas

edit: just realised it might be important that I am using Atom with the Hydrogen plugin to run the script and I have added folder B as a projekt folder.

Comment: Please share the code you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/profile.d would add it to every user's path

~/.bashrc would just be your own

you can always do "$ source ~/.bashrc" to re-read the config files.

Comment: is this solved your quiz?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).